# Put underline before outlets In Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, outlet

Why I must put an underscore before `IBOutlet` names to use them? i.e. when I type this:

```
myLabel.text = @"Hello World";
```

Xcode says me

> Put an underLine before outlet name

It means I must type this instead:

```
_myLabel.text = @"Hello World";
```

Why I must do that?

I use Xcode 6.3.2 And Yosemite 10.10.1

Comment: Please show `myLabel` declaration

Comment: @property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your property declaration, Xcode will automatically synthesize ivar with the same name and underscore prepending. There is simple no var with name you are using. So here is cases:

1. Use it with underscore
2. Use it with the `self.myLabel`
3. Use `@synthesize myLabel = someAnotherName;` or simple `@synthesize myLabel;` to override that bahavior

Answer (score 1):

This is because you need to use @synthesize at the top of the implementation file. The underscore is a quick or short way of writing 'self.'

Comment: It Means If I @synthesize The Outlet,Then No Need That UnderLine??

Comment: Indeed if you use synthesize at the top of the implementation then you can just write 'myLabel.text...' It's an underscore character that you have to use otherwise or self.myLabel

Answer (score 1):

If your myLabel is a property in self class you can use _myLabel to avoid getter/setter method from calling